# static member initialization depending upon initialization of member of another class

Tags: java, static, initialization

I have a super-class namely "AbstractStats" containing some static members. Out of which one static member initialization depends upon another class namely "CommonConfig" (containing configuration values passed from command-line) member which is set by command-line-parser class namely "CLParser".

As static members are initialized at the class loading time.So there will occur inconsistency as by the time "CLParser" parses and sets values in "CommonConfig", the "AbstractStats" class would have been loaded and its static member would have been initialized wrongly.

However I can set the variable explicitly after the command-line arguments have been passed by calling some method.
But I was wondering if there's better way as which can initialize static members only after depending class members have been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Static members are only initialized when the name of the class is used in your code for the first time. So the first time you have `AbstractStats stats = new AbstractStats();` the class loader will initialize the `static` members and then create the object. So if you call the depending class before the `AbstractStats` class, that dependent class will be loaded before `AbstractStats`.

Check out [java class loading](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-java/learn-java-the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html) for more info about how classes and static members are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You must either:

1. Ensure the correct access order is achieved. You may be able to do this in `main` by passing the `args` to `CommonConfig` as the very first step.
2. Make the relationship resilient to order. Make `AbstractStats` call a method in `CommonConfig` every time it needs the value in question. `CommonConfig` must return the real correct data if it has it, otherwise it should return a safe default.

Option `1` is usually easier to achieve but is fragile. It would be very easy for someone to accidentally change the code and break the contract causing strange and difficult-to-find bugs.

Option `2` is better as it can be documented in `CommonConfig` and `AbstractStats` and is resilient.

Answer (score 0):

Try using annotation way you can change the annotation value at run time